# K-complementary pairs using given array of integers effectively

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am very new to programming. I need to find the K-complementary pairs using given array of integers effectively. I have written the below code. It includes the duplication. I need to eliminate that duplication. So please help me to remove that duplication and please suggest if there is a better efficient way to do it.

```
public class KComplexityOfArray {


public static StringBuffer oldFunction(int arr[], int k) {
    int result = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i != j && arr[i] + arr[j] == k) {
                sb.append(arr[i] + "," + arr[j]);
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return sb;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray1 = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 8, -7, -6, 7};
    int[] intArray2 = new int[]{1, 2, 7, 5, 6, 3};
    int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 8, -7, -6};
    int k = 9;
    System.out.println("No of k complementary pairs : " + oldFunction(intArray2, k));
}
```

}

Please anybody help me to sort this out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong, considering two different elements constitute a pair:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
```

Instead you should do `j=i+1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
```

> please suggest if there is a better efficient way to do it.

Your solution has TC of `O(N^2)`. Instead you can reduce it in `O(NlogN)`. See how:

1. Sort the array.
2. Use two index positions, `i` and `j` set to `0` and `N-1` resp.
3. Now, if the sum of `a[i]` and `a[j]` equals `k`, print it. Else if `sum < K`, advance `i` by `1`, else reduce `j` by `1`.
4. Repeat Step 3 till `(i < j)`

Step 1 takes `O(NlogN)` and remaining steps take `O(N)`; combining both incurs `O(NLogN)`

Comment: int j = arr.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == k) {
                sb.append("{" + arr[i] + "," + arr[j] + "}" + ", ");
                result++;
            } else if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) < k) {
                i++;
            } else {
                j--;
            }
        }




this won't work properly with below 
 int[] intArray1 = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 8, -7, -6, 7};
Could you please tell me the problem Saurav

Comment: `i++` inside the loop is wrong as `i++` would happen anyway at the end of `for` loop, eventually leading to double increment of `i`. Use a `while (i < j)` loop instead.

Comment: I tried it and it ended up with out of memory error.
int j = arr.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < j) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == k) {
                sb.append("{" + arr[i] + "," + arr[j] + "}" + ", ");
                result++;
            } else if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) < k) {
                i++;
            } else {
                j--;
            }
        }

Comment: Something is missing with this code. How do you update `i` and `j` when the sum equals `k`? Without updating, you run into an infinite loop. One way is to both increment `i` and decrement `j` in that case. That's fine as long as the values of the array are distinct, but fails if some values are repeated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you should replace

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
```

with

```
for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
```